# How to transfer integer or byte array through socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

yes i did look at the tutorials on sun and they didn`t help in my case, only transferred the first command.

I`ve got a method

```
public void openConnection() throws IOException{

    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5346);

    Socket simSocket = serverSocket.accept();

    is = simSocket.getInputStream();
    os = simSocket.getOutputStream();

    writer = new PrintWriter(os);
    isReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);

    System.out.println("Connection succesfull.");
}
```

and

```
public void sendTo(int command) {
    try {
        writer.println(command);
        writer.flush();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error sending command to the robot");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

in the sending side, and

```
public static void setUpConnection() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 5346);
        is = new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(is);
        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Simulator: connection succesful");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and

```
while (true) {
                intCommand = reader.read();
                ett = reader.readLine(); // does nothing, but without this line it doesn't work
                command = (char) intCommand;
```

in the receiving side. It works perfectly sending a char or an ascii number of a char. What i need is to change this code to send integers or simply array of bytes instead of a char. if i simply leave just InputStream and OutputStream it does receive the first command and thats it, while these methods continuously receives what is sent through sendTo. Even in sockets documentation they only have exmample with sending chars only.

Comment: Look into serialization (create a class that implements serializable or use one of the available serializaton APIs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just code your server to store the received value as an int instead of a char.

Comment: how do i do that exactly, i thought is just a matter of what kind of InputStream or smth to use, since it send the number perfectly, just need to receive it as an byte array and not try to get a char from it

Comment: if the problem is the receiving side then just make sure that side knows what is coming out of the stream so it can store it as the correct data type.